# Jenkins job failed, cannot do scp to remote, Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-keys

I need little help.
In my Jenkinsfile I have stage where I want to execute shell:

sh "sudo scp /home/boris2/webgoat-server-v8.1.0.jar boris3@10.113.80.109:/home/boris3"

but jenkins job failed with output: Permission denied (publickey,password)

I can connect via ssh to remote and I can do a scp command via terminal.
I have try many solutions but cannot find the right one.

Can anyone help?

When I try scp -v I have this output:

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.113.80.109 [10.113.80.109] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.113.80.109:22 as 'boris3'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Sr+ta5yB6J7Kz9FlJoZBy/W3jb0hBeZv4BHcJuDvsE8
debug1: Host '10.113.80.109' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
boris3@10.113.80.109: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: *"I have try many solutions but cannot find the right one"* does not tell us *anything* about what you did try.

Comment: Improve your Question! Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your question? This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand, sorry for that. I have tried to change permission of my folder on remote machine(boris3), tried to add jenkins user to sudoers file on host and remote...can't remember all the things

Answer (score 0):

You can try **scp -v** to see which ssh keys are being used for the communication.
If you were able to connect to the remote machine - as you say - but not as the jenkins user, make sure that **$JENKINS_HOME** directory contains the **.ssh/** directory with the specific ssh keys you need to communicate with the remote machine.

Also i don't think that sudo is necessary in order for scp to work.

Comment: I have tried to change home directory for jenkins so that jenkins user have all permissions, but still got error: debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
boris3@10.113.80.109: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: Also in my new Jenkins_home directory I don't have .ssh/ directory. How can now generate ssh keys and which user should I use?